# Trying to optimize my regex code as it is taking more than a minute to execute

Tags: php, regex, simple-html-dom

My code is used for parsing html , i have used many condition to get my desired output. I am getting what i wanted , but the process is too slow. i tried to optimize as much as possible.Please help to optimize regex expression and my written condition.

```
foreach($html->find('p') as $e){    
                if($e->tag=='p' && $e->class =='Ex'){
        $e->setAttribute('class', 'pick Ex');
        $e->setAttribute('id', 'Ex'.$i);    
        $e->outertext = "<div class=\"imgcontainer\" id='img-container-".$i."'><div class=\"container-div\" id='some_".$i."'><h2 class='imgtitle'>".str_replace('nbsp','',preg_replace('/[^\p{L}\-\(\)\$\s  {0-9} :]/u', '',$e->plaintext))."</h2>";
        $n=$i;  
        $allImgIndexContainer.="<li><a href='#image-container-".$i."'>".str_replace('nbsp','',preg_replace('/[^\p{L}\s\(\)\-\$  {0-9} :]/u', '',$e->plaintext))."</a></li>";            
        $i++; 
        $flag1 = 1;
       } 
    if(preg_match("/<img\s[^<>]*><\/p>/i", $e))
    {

if(($e->tag=='p' && $e->class=='Image') or ($e->tag=='p' && $e->class=='MsoNormal'))
            {
                    $tomatch = $e->parentNode();
        if (strpos($tomatch,'<td') == true) 
        {  
                $e->setAttribute('class', 'pickmeimg');             
        $e->outertext = "<div class=\"img-wapper\">".str_replace(' ', ' ', str_replace('Â','',$e->innertext))."</div>";
        $flag2 = 1;
                    }  
                } 
       }
if(($e->tag=='p' && $e->class=='Image') or ($e->tag=='p' && $e->class=='Source') or ($e->tag=='p' && $e->class=='MsoNormal'))
   {   
        if($flag2 ==1)
        { $btn = "<div class='download-sub-menu clearfix'><div class='dl' onclick=\"dpt('".$n."');\">Download</div></div>";
        }
        else
        {
            $btn = ''; 
        }
        $e->setAttribute('class', 'pickmeimg'); 
        $e->outertext = "<p class='image-footer'>".str_replace(' ', ' ', str_replace('Â','',preg_replace('/#.*?(<img.+?>).*?#is', '',$e->plaintext)))."</p></div>".$btn."</div>";
        $flag3 = 1;
        $flag2 = 0;
    }

}
```

Comment: Looks like `if($e->tag=='p'` is redundant. What are you trying to achieve with the code? Please add this to the question.

Comment: @stribizhev  ""$e->tag=='p' && $e->class=='Image'  "" give me all paragraph of the html where the class is Image

Comment: The problem is here `preg_replace('/#.*?(<img.+?>).*?#is', '',$e->plaintext)`, but I'm not sure what you intend to do with this code...

Comment: I just wanted to replace all the character excluding image tag @nhahtdh

Comment: Why are you using regular expressions to perform tag matching when you're already using an HTML parsing library? This is like jumping out of an airplane holding an umbrella instead of using the parachute you already have strapped to your back.

Comment: @Phylogenesis , i have tried what you said , but that is not serving my need. btw thanks for looking into it.

Comment: I have one more question if any body have idea in regular expression..i need to remove all the character from a string except IMAGE TAG. I have used above but seem like this code is slowing down my entire process as @nhahtdh said

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed most of the functionality from php to jquery and the process is now very fast as i wanted.